# Android Huawei MediasSessionCompat

Tags: android, android-support-library

I started to use MediaSessionCompat (22.2.0, now 22.2.1) instead of RemoteControlClient and I see NullPointerException on Huawei phones when calling setActive(true) on MediaSessionCompact instance. It has problem to registerMediaButtonEventReceiver. Everything worked ok with RemoteControlClient and it works ok now on all other devices.

Any idea why error bellow happens on Huawei phones(android 4.4.2, 4.4.4)?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1481)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
   at android.media.IAudioService$Stub$Proxy.registerMediaButtonIntent(IAudioService.java:1689)
   at android.media.AudioManager.registerMediaButtonIntent(AudioManager.java:2223)
   at android.media.AudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(AudioManager.java:2208)
   at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompatApi18.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(MediaSessionCompatApi18.java:35)
   at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$MediaSessionImplBase.update(MediaSessionCompat.java:1286)
   at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$MediaSessionImplBase.setActive(MediaSessionCompat.java:1149)
   at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.setActive(MediaSessionCompat.java:240)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this is HUAWEI's fault. Here's some more information in the comments: https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/YgdTkKFxz7d

Comment: @vandzi, did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @tom-hennen no. But in new version of support library it shouldn't at least crash.